# Ручная сборка Android проекта, включая зависимости

Tags: android, bash

Пишу небольшой Bash-скрипт для сборки Android проектов, т. к. использую дистрибутив для архитектуры ARM, для которого Google официально не собирает инструменты разработки, использую «что есть» (aapt, zipalign, aidl и т. д.; 24 API). Соответственно, использовать систему сборки Gradle не могу.

Так вот, вопрос: как собрать проект, включая библиотеки (AppCompat, например)? Манулы по ручной сборке проекта в Интернете достаточно, а вот как собирать проект, включая сторонние библиотеки — я не нашёл. Какие параметры утилит aapt, javac, dx.jar необходимо указывать?

Как-то у меня получилось собрать проект с библиотекой AppCompat — приложение работало без падений, но после рефакторинга и добавления новых фич в скрипт, что-то пошло не так, и при попытке запуска AppCompatActivity выходит ошибка «ResID not found».

В общем, если кто-то разбирается в этом деле — пишите, отправлю полный лог процесса сборки. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще это путь героя - преклоняюсь:

Вкратце путь такой (без обфускации - обфускация добавляет еще пару шагов):

1. Генерируем `R.java` - используется инструментарий `aapt`
2. Далее компилируем обычным JDK исходники включая `R.java` до `.class`
3. Потом переводим JVM объектники `.class` в Dalvik объектники `.dex` используем инструмент `dx`
4. Собираем APK архив - опять используем `aapt`
5. Подписываем архив - инструмент `jarsigner`
6. Выравниваем архив - инструмент `zipalign`

Слегка устаревший [мануал здесь](http://geosoft.no/development/android.html)

Comment: Пустой проект, используя **только framework**, у меня собирается, а вот как правильно подключить **сторонние библиотеки** — уже проблема. Получать библиотеки и их зависимости из репозитория *Maven Google* у меня получилось. Распаковываю их (.aar) как ZIP-архив, генерирую R.java класс библиотеки, если папка **res** не пуста (также включаю эти папки с ресурсами во время сборки APK-файла), *.jar* файлы включаю в параметрах компилятора Java. Но, при запуске всё того же пустого проекта, но используя уже **AppCompatActivity** (также, конечно же, использую соответсвующий стиль) приложение падает.

Comment: Падает приложение с ошибкой **«ResID not found»**, но, в разобранном приложении, в файле **public.xml**, требуемый ресурс имеется (**abc_screen_toolbar**), но его ID не соответствует ID этого же ресурса в сгенерированном файле библиотеки R.java, как-будто при сборке ID-шники смещаются. Вот, пытаюсь понять, что я упускаю при сборке проекта с библиотеками.